# Excel Help if is number search

Tags: excel, formula

I'm working on an excel file and I don't understand, how do I do the following formula?

```
IF(S4=2022; BDD!N3; IF(S4=2020; BDD!N2; IF(S4=2019; BDD!N1; "")))
```

In cell S5 print:

- If S4 contains 2022, then from the tab 'BDD'
  print cell N3.
- If S4 contains 2020, then from the tab 'BDD'
  print cell N2
- If S4 contains 2019, then from the tab 'BDD' cell print N1

Comment: what does that formula do that is in error?  It looks good to me.

Comment: basic excel formula error

Comment: Then maybe you use `,` instead of `;` as the delimiter or some other character.